# How Not to mix progress bar data with other output?

Tags: rust, output

I have a little stacked with a progress bars.

This is a example program:

```
use indicatif::*;
use std::{sync::mpsc, sync::mpsc::*, thread};

pub enum Output {
    Finish,
    Tick,
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Output>();

    let join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        handle_output_messages(100_000, rx);
    });

    (0..100_000).for_each(|_| tx.send(Output::Tick).unwrap());

    tx.send(Output::Finish).unwrap();

    join_handle.join().unwrap();
}

pub fn handle_output_messages(total_things: u64, rx: Receiver<Output>) {
    let multi_bar = MultiProgress::new();
    let progress_bar = multi_bar.add(ProgressBar::new(total_things));

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for output in rx {
            match output {
                Output::Tick => progress_bar.inc(1),
                Output::Finish => {
                    progress_bar.finish();
                    (0..600).for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    multi_bar.join_and_clear().unwrap();
}
```

if you try to run it, you will see, that progress bar messages will be mixed with iterated numbers. This it not good for me, but I have no any idea, how to fix this behavior.

Maybe anybody can help me?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. When I run your code, I see a progress bar counting to 100_000. After it completes, I see numbers printed from 0 to about 120, before the process exits with `thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'cannot access stdout during shutdown'`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard `println!` with the progress bars isn't going to work, since they're going to overwrite eachother. Instead, use [ProgressBar::println](https://docs.rs/indicatif/0.11.0/indicatif/struct.ProgressBar.html#method.println), which prints the message above the progress bar without overwriting it.

Comment: Yes, good idea, but I want to show some info After the progress bar will shown.